# Regular expression how to do the following test: if the expression contains '{' then accept the expression only if found another '}'?

Tags: regex, xsd

I need to run the following test: 
if the an expression contains '{' then accept the expression only if found another '}' 
Valid expressions would be are 'aaa{aaa}aaa', '{aa}' , 'a{aa{aa}aa}aa', '{a{a}a}' and such ...
How can i do that?

if it matters i will run this test within an XSD document...

Answer (score 2):

The language you are describing (which is closely related to the Dyck language) is context-free, not regular (type 2 in the Chomsky hierarchy). That said, it is impossible that a basic regular expression could be used to construct an acceptor for words of this language.

However, stack machines can decide the word problem for the type of language you describe. To implement this, you should tokenize the String into characters, iterate over each character and if you discover an opening parenthesis increase a counter initialized to 0 by one. If you discover a closing parenthesis decrease it by one. If the invariant `counter >= 0` holds during the entire execution and if the final state of the counter is 0, accept the word.

Comment: Thanks, I have ended up doing the Easiest thing, just duplication the basic structure of  a{a}a == [^{}]*{[^{}]+}[^{}]* and each time add more curly braces of example that is expression matches is for 4    [^{}]*{([^{}]+|[^{}]*{[^{}]+}[^{}]*|[^{}]*{[^{}]*{[^{}]+}[^{}]*})[^{}]*}[^{}]*

Answer (score 1):

For the reasons Michael Schmeißer outlines, the language described in the question cannot be recognized by XSD regular expressions.  (It can probably be recognized by Perl-compatible patterns, which have long since left the class-3 languages behind, but XSD does not use the back-references and other devices that give Perl expressions that extra power.)

### Regular approximations

Your comment on MS's answer suggests that you may be willing to settle for a regular approximation to the language described in the question.  If so, then you have a choice between a regular subset language, which accepts only words of the original language but may wrongly reject some of them, or a regular superset language, which accepts all the words of the language but wrongly accepts some non-words as well.

#### The approximation in the comment

The expression given in the comment on MS's answer is a regular subset.  It has three obvious limitations:

- It allows braces to nest at most three deep.
- It requires at least one pair of braces (it does not accept the string "`aaa`").
- It allows at most one pair of braces at each level of nesting (it does not accept "`a{a}a{a}a`").

Some limit like the first of these is unavoidable; you can pick a number higher than three but there will always be a maximum depth of nesting in a regular subset.  The other two, however, are not necessary and can be avoided by a systematic development of the subset expression.

### Developing a subset expression systematically

#### Start with BNF

Taking, for simplicity, the language illustrated in the original posting, we can express it in a BNF-like notation this way:

```
<S> ::= <empty> | <S> a | <S> { <S> } .
<empty> ::= .
```

Or, in an extended BNF:

```
S ::= (a|{S})*
```

#### Rewrite to make the nesting levels explicit

We can then rewrite this to track the nesting (in the style of an affix grammar) this way:

```
S ::= (a|{S1})*
S1 ::= (a|{S2})*
S2 ::= (a|{S3})*
etc.
```

At a chosen level *n*, we can end the recursion (and thus make the language regular) this way:

```
Sn ::= a*
```

#### Substitute RHS for LHS

We can then build the regex by substituting, one level at a time:

```
S = (a|{S1})*
  = (a|{(a|{S2})*})*
  = (a|{(a|{(a|{S3})*})*})*
etc.
```

In this case, it boils down to this:  to allow nesting *n* levels deep, we begin with *n* copies of the string "`(a|{`", continue with "`a*`", and end with *n* copies of the string "`})*`".  To allow characters other than `a`, we can rewrite with `[^{}]` instead of `a`.

#### Result for *n* = 4

If we stop the substitutions with four levels of nested braces, we get the expression

```
([^{}]|{([^{}]|{([^{}]|{([^{}]|{[^{}]*})*})*})*})*
```

#### A superset expression as an alternative

If it's important that no legal expression ever be rejected, we can turn this into a superset expression by replacing the central `[^{}]*` with `.*` or `(.|\n)*`; we then have a regex which accepts (a) strings with correctly nested braces no more than four deep, and also (b) strings with braces that nest four deep, containing arbitrary strings at the innermost level (so the fifth, sixth, or nth level of nesting is not necessarily correct).

```
([^{}]|{([^{}]|{([^{}]|{([^{}]|{[(.|\n)*})*})*})*})*
```

If by contrast it's important that no illegal expression ever be accepted, it's better to stick with a subset expression.